# Is the Unix Timestamp(UTC) and Java UTC same? Can we compare?

Tags: java, php, time, utc, unix-timestamp

I am afraid, this would seem duplication of many questions on this same context, but i couldn't find any answers for me in that.

What i want is a comparison between two UTC's. One generated in java and one in PHP. I find both UTC (millisecond strings) entirely different.

The real case is an expiry calculation for authorization. I can allow a 3 minute expiry for a token. The token may be coming from any of the Local servers all over the world.

Can any one suggest a soln for this?...

thanks for your help

Comment: If this question _is_ a duplicate of any of those others (and I don't know this), the lack of a suitable answer is not a good enough reason to re-ask it. What you should have done was offer up a bounty on the original.

Comment: ... or at the very least include links to some of the ones you looked at.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [PHP timestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) is the number of *seconds* since the Unix epoch. Java's libraries use the number of *milliseconds* since the Unix epoch. So I'd expect the PHP value to be one thousandth of the Java value.

But yes, it's the same epoch - both UTC, both midnight on January 1st 1970, in the ISO calendar. If the servers agree on time to a reasonable extent, you should be fine. However, 3 minutes is a *relatively* small window - how confident are you that all the machines involved are syncing with a network time server reasonably frequently?

Comment: Its worth noting that UTC has leap seconds which netither Java nor PHP support.  I tend to refer to Java's currentTimeMillis as GMT. ;)

Comment: @Peter: Time is a detestable thing, apparently ;-)

Comment: UTC isn't even an initalism for anything. ;) The English wanted Coordinated Universal Time and the French wanted Temps Universel Coordonné so they compromised on something which favours neither.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I think [TAI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Atomic_Time) would be a more appropriate reference point than GMT. If the UK ever decides to adopt European time, then GMT may become an hour later than UTC/TAI etc.

Comment: Possibly, except GMT by not having leap seconds effectively has a slightly longer second. i.e. the years are the same length.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: But TAI doesn't have leap seconds either, and doesn't have the baggage of being associated with a specific place (where the time zone may change in the future).

Comment: I think it unlikely the English will drop Greenwich Mean Time given Greenwich is in England. They resisted adopting the Greogian Calender for hundreds of years.

Comment: However TAI is relative to UTC and has the same length of second .  What computers do is base their calculations on having 24*60*60 seconds in every day and use NTP to correct for drift.  Leap seconds just appear as drift but it effectively means that in computers the length of a second is slightly longer than in TAI or UTC.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: But it's entirely feasible that we may move to European time, even in the winter. At that point, either Greenwich would never obey GMT, or GMT would be an hour out from UTC. Either way, referring to GMT here is less-than-ideal IMO.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Okay, I think I see what you mean, yes.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: It'll be nice when leap seconds finally die :)

Comment: Supporting true UTC so every year had the proper number of seconds would be even more complicated than the current timezones system. esp. as I am not sure all countries use leap seconds.  For most cases it is simpler to assume UTC = GMT. ;)

Comment: As the rotation of the earth is slowing down, I fear the number of leap seconds will increase.  I think we will have two definitions of a second. One which is scientific and always the same length, and one which is based on the length of a year or day.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure they are both *really* milliseconds, as "unix time" is traditionally in seconds.

Failing that, yes, "seconds since the UNIX epoch" should be the same whether you calculate it in Java and PHP.  You might post code if you are not sure that you have done this correctly.

If that is done right, make sure your clocks are synchronized (e.g. with `ntp`).  This is a hugely common reason for conditions like "must be within 3 minutes" to fail spuriously.